# Finding all regular expression/s from a value

Tags: java, regex

I have a variable having some URL and a file containing 100's of regular expression. How can i find which regular expression/s will hold true for that variable. I don't want to do the pattern match for each and every pattern in the file. Looking for performance efficient solution.

Comment: Have you benchmarked a pattern match for a pattern on each of the patterns? If so, what were the results and what are you aiming for?

Comment: *I don't want to do the pattern match for each and every pattern in the file.* And my kids don't want to get up and go to school in the morning. Good luck with that!

Comment: If you want to have the list of which amoung hundreds of regexes match a given string, there aren't that many possible solutions.

Comment: I know there will not be many matching patterns. I'm just thinking if I go one by one with each pattern and see if the variable value matches with it or not and if there are millions of pattern in the file....how will it scale

Comment: I'm just trying to approach this problem out of curiosity. The problem is simple - I have to print all the matching patterns (for the given string) from the file. So far, i have only read and tried - if a value matches a regular expression or not but not the other way out (if a regular expression matches a value or not)

Answer (score 0):

While, ultimately, you won't get away with a "true" performance-efficient solution, there are some simple heuristics you can utilize to help cut down on the number of patterns you need to evaluate.

For instance, try "grouping" patterns using simplified versions. Consider the two patterns

```
[a-z]\d[a-z]
[a-z]{3}
```

Any string matching both of these patterns will also match the pattern `[a-z].[a-z]`. If you skip the previous two patterns if the more general pattern doesn't match, you'll (likely) save on overall processing time. The more you can generalize, the more patterns you can eliminate at once. The ultimate expression of this is hierarchical, in which patterns follow a  file-system-like organization of groups. While the worst-case performance of this system is worse than just going through all the patterns, the average case will likely be somewhat better as different groups of patterns are eliminated.

You're not going to get better than `O(n)` performance on the number of regexes, but you're likely to have savings on the coefficient of `n`.